# What is the correct type hint for dynamo db resource in boto3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

I have added `ruff` to an existing project and one of my rules are flake8-annotations. I am struggling a bit with the type hint for a function that does this:

```
def _dynamodb_resource():
    return boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name=REGION)
```

In the docs, it says `boto3.resources.base.ServiceResource` would be the correct choice however this gives me another warning that the ServiceResource does not have a Table attribute. Is there a way to get this working without any warnings?

```
from boto3.resources.base import ServiceResource

dynamodb_resource = _dynamodb_resource()
table = dynamodb_resource.Table("table") <-- Unresolved attribute reference 'Table' for class 'ServiceResource'

def _dynamodb_resource() -> ServiceResource:
    return boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name=REGION)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boto3 types are generated at runtime, so they tend to cause problems with static checkers. There are 3rd party libraries to remedy that, namely this one: https://pypi.org/project/boto3-stubs/

So in your case it will look something like this:

```
from mypy_boto3_dynamodb.service_resource import DynamoDBServiceResource

def get_dynamodb_resource() -> DynamoDBServiceResource:
    return boto3.resource("dynamodb")
```